# Head.js not loading script files

Tags: jquery, head.js

I'm trying to use head.js but I'm dying here to make it work. Here is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>assets/scripts/lib/head.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    head.js("http://localhost/compra/assets/scripts/lib/jquery-1.6.1.min.js");
    head.ready(function ()
    {
        $('#date').datepicker();
    });
</script>
```

I have tried with `head.ready()` and without it but Google Chrome always returns this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function
```

The URL for the script file is correct.

Comment: are you actually attaching the jquery.js ?

Comment: what do you mean? I have the header.js() and the link to it, the link is correct...

Comment: Do you have anything other than head.js and jquery on the page? also if you have solved your problem please post an answer and mark it as solved. to help others who might have the same issue.

Comment: what he means is that you post your solution as an answer below and then click the checkmark to indicate that it's the solution.  You are allowed to officially answer your own questions here.  That way everyone reading this in the future will benefit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have found the solution.

I have to add

`$(document).ready()` right after`head.ready(function ()`

```
head.ready(function () {

   $(document).ready(function({
     alert('test');
   });

}
```

And it worked.

I don't know if that is 100% correct. It's not on the head.js website.

Hope that helps =)

**PS: Really sorry for not posting the solution correctly at first time**

Comment: @AaronLee Great new! :)